# How to get to child-child objects using bracket notation?

Tags: typescript

My Object looks like this:

```typescript
let obj = {
  foo: {
    bar: 'value'
  }
}
```

I want to access the value of bar via the string 'foo.bar'.

But `obj['foo.bar']` is not working.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each property must be in its own bracket.

```
obj['foo']['bar']; // 'value'
```

So if you have a string 'foo.bar', you must split that string into parts.

```
let obj = {
  foo: {
    bar: 'value'
  }
}

let paths = 'foo.bar'.split('.');

let value = paths.reduce((acc, path) => {
  acc = acc[path];
  return acc;
},obj)
```